# How to group excel rows on multiple levels using excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem of grouping the excel rows based upon row data. Below is the sample data. [image: Sample data for grouping the rows]

I want to group the data based upon the Resource, Metro and Geo. [image: Data after grouping]

I have started to write a macro below but need some help in getting this done.

```
Public Sub GroupCells()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim GeoRange As Range
    Dim MetroRange As Range
    Dim ResourceRange As Range
    Dim GeosRange As Range
    Dim MetrosRange As Range
    Dim unionRange As Range


    Set myRange = Range("Resource")
    Set GeoRange = Range("Geo")
    Set MetroRange = Range("Metro")
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    Set TypesRange = myRange.SpecialCells(xlTextValues)
    Set GeosRange = GeoRange.SpecialCells(xlTextValues)
    Set MetrosRange = MetroRange.SpecialCells(xlTextValues)
    Set unionRange = Union(TypesRange, GeosRange, MetrosRange)
    For Each grp In unionRange
    grp.Rows.Group
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: (Quick note - what sheet do you want to get the row count of? Currently, it's going to grab the row count of whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.  To specify, add the worksheet name before `Cells()` and `Rows.Count` like you did for the `specialCells`)

Comment: Why not use the old Data Subtotal function?

Comment: recording a macro yields:     ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(3), _
        Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True